# Import excel 2D array to tuple without convert to 1D CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I have a 2D array in excel need import to CPLEX.

[image]

Normally, I use:

```
{string} part = ...;
{string} operation = ...;
float runtime[part, operation] = ...;
```

However, can I import it as a tuple without convert to 1D

```
tuple Trun
{
    string part;
    string operation;
}
{Trun} run = {<i, o> | i in part, o in operation};
float runtime[run] = ...;
```

Or is there any way to convert `runtime[part, operation]` to `runtime[run]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can

"**convert runtime[part, operation] to runtime[run]**"

See

```
{string} part = {"A","B","C"};
{string} operation = {"1","2"};
float runtime[part, operation] = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];

tuple Trun
{
string p;
string o;
}
{Trun} run = {<i, o> | i in part, o in operation};


float runtime2[r in run] = runtime[r.p,r.o];

execute
{
writeln(runtime);
writeln(runtime2);
}
```

that gives

```
[[1 2]
         [3 4]
         [5 6]]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Comment: Thank you, Alex. How about the way of importing 2D Array to tuple?

Comment: You could use sheetRead to read a 2D array and turn that into a tuple set. have a look at the oil example in CPLEX_Studio128\opl\examples\opl\oil